# "TypeError: ((n.event.special[g.origType] || {}).handle || g.handler).apply is not a function" error from jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp library

Tags: jquery, errors, library

I'm getting an error in console

> Uncaught TypeError: ((n.event.special[g.origType] || {}).handle || g.handler).apply is not a function
>
> at HTMLDocument.dispatch (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp:3)
>   at HTMLDocument.r.handle (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp:3)

from jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp library, just on entering website. I've noticed, that the error occurs only, if I don't have dev-tools (F12) opened, when refreshing the site.

[image]

Everything is up-to-date.
WP ver: 5.4
php: 7.4

Plugins:
Contact Form 7
Really Simple SSL

Theme:
Consaltup

Comment: I'm seeing this same error. Did you ever get a resolution?

Comment: Nope, just left it unresolved. How close is your env to mine?